# Prerender.io not caching my pages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, seo, prerender

So I'm trying to set up [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) for my AngularJS application with a ExpressJS backend following this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io). I have done exactly as instructed, the only difference being I have enabled `HTML5mode`. I have included the `meta(name="fragment" content="!")` in my `index.jade` and the prerender token to my `server.js` file (using the [prerender-node](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node) package) but somehow my pages do not seem to be cached or generate any crawl stats.

***config.coffee***

```
angular.config ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider','toastrConfig',($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,toastrConfig)->
    $stateProvider
    .state 'home',
        url:'/'
        templateUrl: 'html/main.html'
        controller:'mainController'

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

    $locationProvider.html5Mode
        enabled: true
        requireBase: false

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix '!'
]
```

***Server.JS***

```
// Here we require the prerender middleware that will handle requests from Search Engine crawlers 
// We set the token only if we're using the Prerender.io service 
app.use(require('prerender-node')
.set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://www.mydomain.co.com/')
.set('prerenderToken', 'my-token'));


// HTML5MODE settings
// ------------------------------------------------------
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use('/html', express.static(__dirname + '/public/html'));

// Routes
// ------------------------------------------------------
require('./app/js/routes/routes.js')(app);

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this line from your config:

```
.set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://www.mydomain.co.com/')
```

The service URL should point to a Prerender server, so you shouldn't set that to your website URL.

Comment: I made the change but its still not caching

Comment: does it take a while for the stats to be shown after you tell the google search bot to crawl your page?

Comment: It depends. Send me an email and I'll look into it. todd@prerender.io

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure that you have implemented the correct prerender.io configuration in your Angular App.

I tested the below code and correctly cached it in the prerender.io dashboard.

```
File: ../static/routes.json content

["/","/content/terms-conditions","/content/about-us",..]

File: /config/webpack.production.js

const axios = require('axios');
const routesData = require('../static/routes.json'),

console.log("PRERENDER.io caching start for Crawler Bots to SEO indexing");
const host = 'your domain name with http or https';
const prerenderToken = '****';
const prerenderUrl = 'https://api.prerender.io/recache';

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
console.log("Start date time : "+dateTime);

for (const route of routesData) {
    const fullRoute = host + route + '/index.html';
    console.log(`Caching URL ${fullRoute}`);

    var prerednerData = {
        'prerenderToken': prerenderToken,
        'url': fullRoute
    };

    axios.post(prerenderUrl, prerednerData)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Product URL: '+prerednerData['url']);
        console.log('Status Code: '+response.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Product URL: '+prerednerData['url']);
        console.log('Error: '+error);
    });
}    

File: .htaccess

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "****"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Pre-render HTML for search crawler bots to indexing
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        # Only proxy the request to Prerender.io if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.globalshop.com.au/$2 [NE,L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domainname.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-disallow.txt [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html

</IfModule>
```

Cheers!